# Adding Legends in Graphs without tidy data

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
#Plot the in sample forecasts against the actual values
#Build the confidence interval

Upper95 <- fcast1 + 1.96*sqrt(Var1)

Lower95 <- fcast1 - 1.96*sqrt(Var1)

Upper80 <- fcast1 + 1.28*sqrt(Var1)

Lower80 <- fcast1 - 1.28*sqrt(Var1)
#Create a data frame

dfb <- data.frame(TeslaWeeklyPrices$Date,fcast1,TeslaWeeklyPrices$TeslaPrices,Upper95,Lower95,Upper80,Lower80)
#Make the Plot

Plot1 <- ggplot(dfb, aes(x=TeslaWeeklyPrices.Date, y=TeslaWeeklyPrices.TeslaPrices))+ 
  geom_ribbon(data=dfb,aes(ymin=Upper95,ymax=Lower95),fill = "slategray2")+ 

  geom_ribbon(data=dfb,aes(ymin=Upper80,ymax=Lower80),fill = "bisque")+ 

  geom_line(data=dfb, aes(x=TeslaWeeklyPrices.Date, y=fcast1),size=1, color="red1")+

  geom_point(shape = 19,  fill = "white", colour = "blue" ,size = 1)+ 

  theme_light(base_size = 11) +

  ylab("Tesla Stock price ($)") + xlab("Date (weeks)")

Plot1
```

That is my code for my graph.

[image]

That is how it looks. I want to add legends in my graph without having to tidy my data. Because then I can not format my graph as I want.

After the useful comment I got.

Upper95 <- fcast1 + 1.96*sqrt(Var1)

Lower95 <- fcast1 - 1.96*sqrt(Var1)

Upper80 <- fcast1 + 1.28*sqrt(Var1)

Lower80 <- fcast1 - 1.28*sqrt(Var1)

dfb <- data.frame(TeslaWeeklyPrices$Date,fcast1,TeslaWeeklyPrices$TeslaPrices,Upper95,Lower95,Upper80,Lower80)

Plot1 <- ggplot(dfb, aes(x=TeslaWeeklyPrices.Date, y=TeslaWeeklyPrices.TeslaPrices))+

geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Upper95, ymax=Lower95, fill='95% prediction level')) +

geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Upper80, ymax=Lower80, fill='80% prediction level')) +

geom_line(data=dfb, aes(x=TeslaWeeklyPrices.Date, y=fcast1,
color="Predicted Values"),size=1)+

geom_point(shape = 19, aes(color = "Observed Values"),
fill = "white", size = 1 ,)+

scale_fill_manual(values=c('95% prediction level'='slategray2', '80% prediction level'="bisque"), breaks=c('95% prediction level', '80% prediction level')) +

scale_color_manual(values=c("Predicted Values"="red","Observed Values"= "blue"), breaks=c('Predicted Values', 'Observed Values'))+
guides(color=guide_legend(title=NULL),fill=guide_legend(title=NULL) ) +

theme(legend.margin = margin(b=0, t=-1000))+

theme_light(base_size = 12)

Plot1

That is my new code.
[image]

So how can my blue points look as points in the Legend and not as a line. And how can i det the margin to 0 between my 2 legends?

[image]

Can I format the background color of this so it looks like an independent part and not as part of the graph?

[image]

That is an example I saw in one paper.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I do have a bit of an issue with the comment:

> I want to add legends in my graph without having to tidy my data.
> Because then I can not format my graph as I want.

Tidying your data is often the best solution to do just that (format the graph as you want), but I kind of agree it might be more straightforward in this case to just "brute force" the legend into place.  I'll show you how.

Since I don't have your data, I made up my own to mirror that you shared:

```
set.seed(1234)

time <- 1:50
Var1 <- unlist(lapply(time, function(x) rnorm(1, 1, 0.01)))
fcast1 <- unlist(lapply(time, function(x) { x * rnorm(1, 0.1, 0.01)}))
Upper95 <- fcast1 + 1.96*sqrt(Var1)
Lower95 <- fcast1 - 1.96*sqrt(Var1)
Upper80 <- fcast1 + 1.28*sqrt(Var1)
Lower80 <- fcast1 - 1.28*sqrt(Var1)

dfb <- data.frame(time, fcast1, Upper95, Lower95, Upper80, Lower80)
```

And the plot:

```
ggplot(dfb, aes(time, fcast1)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Upper95, ymax=Lower95), fill='slategray2') +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Upper80, ymax=Lower80), fill='bisque') +
  geom_line(size=1, color='red1') +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

To create the legend *without* having Tidy data, you need to make the legend piece by piece, but still use `ggplot` to do so.  Legends are created for aesthetics that are not part of the coordinate system in `ggplot2` that are inside of `aes()`.  Therefore, to make the legend appear, you only need to put the aesthetic modifiers `fill` and `color` inside the `aes()` part of each `geom_*()` function.

It's not quite that simple though, but once you understand how it works it becomes more clear.  The value you assign to `fill=` or `color=` inside `aes()` will be used for the *label* in the legend, and not the color.  You will have to specify color with a `scale_*()` function.

```
ggplot(dfb, aes(time, fcast1)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Upper95, ymax=Lower95, fill='Upper')) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Upper80, ymax=Lower80, fill='Lower')) +
  geom_line(size=1, aes(color="Forecast")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('Upper'='slategray2', 'Lower'='bisque'), breaks=c('Upper', 'Lower')) +
  scale_color_manual(values='red1') +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

That looks more like it, but it's not perfect.  Perhaps you would want the line and fill boxes in the legend to become "one" legend box instead?  If that's the case, you can't really do that (because they span two different aesthetic modifiers, `fill` and `color`); however, we can make the same effect if we do a few things:

1. Remove the title for the color legend
2. Change the title for the fill legend
3. Use the `theme` elements and margins to move the legends closer together to look as one

Here you can see how you might do that:

```
p + # this is the code from above
  guides(
    color=guide_legend(title=NULL),
    fill=guide_legend(title='Legend')
  ) +
  theme(legend.margin = margin(b=0, t=-13))
```

[image]

#### EDIT:

OP asked if the points could appear on the chart as well.  They certainly can, and you have to use a similar method to do that.  You can just add `color=` into `aes()` for `geom_point()` like before:

```
ggplot(dfb, aes(time, fcast1)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Upper95, ymax=Lower95, fill='Upper')) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Upper80, ymax=Lower80, fill='Lower')) +
  geom_line(size=1, aes(color="Forecast")) +
  geom_point(size=1, aes(color='Actual Values'), shape=19) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('Upper'='slategray2', 'Lower'='bisque'), breaks=c('Upper', 'Lower')) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('Forecast'='red1', 'Actual Values'='blue')) +
  theme_light() +
  guides(
    color=guide_legend(title=NULL),
    fill=guide_legend(title='Legend')
  ) +
  theme(legend.margin = margin(b=0, t=-13))
```

[image]

One small problem there... you'll notice the icon (called "glyph") next to "Actual Values" and "Forecast" is a line + a point.  I think you'd prefer to have a point be the glyph for the point and a line be the glyph for the line.  We can't do that in the same legend (they are both part of the `color` legend)... so we can fix that by separating "Actual Values" into another legend.  In this case, we'll just use the `shape` aesthetic modifier and have a third legend that also has no title.

```
ggplot(dfb, aes(time, fcast1)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Upper95, ymax=Lower95, fill='Upper')) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Upper80, ymax=Lower80, fill='Lower')) +
  geom_line(size=1, aes(color="Forecast")) +
  geom_point(size=1, aes(shape='Actual Values'), color='blue') +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('Upper'='slategray2', 'Lower'='bisque'), breaks=c('Upper', 'Lower')) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('Forecast'='red1')) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=19) +
  theme_light() +
  guides(
    color=guide_legend(title=NULL),
    shape=guide_legend(title=NULL),
    fill=guide_legend(title='Legend')
  ) +
  theme(legend.margin = margin(b=0, t=-13))
```

[image]

Now you have all the information needed to become a `ggplot` master :).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is a very insightful one. My only concern is that I have the dots as well which are the actual values. Hence, I would like to ask if the dots of my actual values can be shown on the legend.

Comment: You are the best

Comment: One point I forgot to explain:  the argument `breaks=` in `scale_fill_manual()` is there to function as the way to order "Upper" and "Lower" in that order.  By default, `ggplot` reverts here to organizing those alphabetically, but setting `breaks=` sets the order in the way I specify for the vector.